# Code optimisation removing duplicates in VB

Tags: vb.net, optimization, duplicates

I'm looking to optimise my code. Specifically this process

1. Calculate a group of locations (basically squares on a grid)
2. Have a list of all the locations that have been calculated
3. Then I go through all these locations, 1 at a time.

The issue I'm having is removing or not including duplicate locations in the list. I've tried having a list of integers (integers to represent the location) but it's still very slow. To give you an idea of the numbers: I'm talking at least 15,000 different location calculations and around 1,000,000 possible locations.

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use hashset instead of a list, and duplicates will be removed automatically

Comment: How about using BitArray and flagging the element with 1 if it is calculated, 0 otherwise?

Comment: MarcinJuraszek: I've just tried using hashsets and it's over 10 times slower, but thanks for the idea I hadn't thought of using them.

Comment: shahkalpesh: That would still mean stepping through each element in the array and checking for a 1 or 0. As I'm looking at around 1,000,000 possible array elements this works out to be slower (I used a similar method originally), but thanks for the idea.

Comment: How about showing some code? Perhaps there's a trivial error in your attempt in using hashset.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I remove duplicates from an string array, perhaps it will be of help to you:

```
  Dim OneDimensionalTable(1000) As String

  ....

  OneDimensionalTable = RemoveDuplicates(OneDimensionalTable)

  .....


 Private Function RemoveDuplicates(ByVal items As String()) As String()

    Dim noDupsArrList As New ArrayList()
    For i As Integer = 0 To items.Length - 1
        If Not noDupsArrList.Contains(items(i).Trim()) Then
            noDupsArrList.Add(items(i).Trim())
        End If
    Next

    Dim uniqueItems As String() = New String(noDupsArrList.Count - 1) {}
    noDupsArrList.CopyTo(uniqueItems)
    Return uniqueItems

End Function
```

Comment: This is one of the ways I've tried. The problem is running through the RemoveDuplicates using .Contains basically means checking if the test item is equal to each of the items in the array - which works out to be 15,000 if statements (As I've got 15,000 entries in the list) and that's just checking the first item. It works out to be 15,000+14999+14998+14997 etc... which is 112,492,499 if statements.

Comment: You shouldn't. Sorting the array before scanning would reduce the complexity to O(N log N) -- and hashing to O(N).

Comment: Sorting does reduce the number of if statements, however the process of sorting adds a reasonable number of if statements (if item1>item2... if item1>item3 etc. - this adds up to the same number of if statements in total I think). And hashing is the same number of if statements it's just done when the list is made as opposed to after it's finished being made.

Comment: OK - so can you then change your approach.  Instead of removing duplicates once your table is built, can you just ensure you don't add any duplicates as the table is being built.  That is to say, keep all the numbers you have added todate in a list and then before adding a new number in your table check the list to see if it is a duplicate (and if it is don't add it).  All things being equal you would only need to check  the list about half way thru for each duplicate number you run into before deciding not to add it.